# How to hide lines from adjoining faces in Fusion360 drawings?

Tags: cad, drawings

I'm designing a holding tank with a complex set of planar faces in Fusion 360 and want to produce face-oriented 1:1 drawings to fabricate a cardboard mockup for interference testing. I'm creating Named Views in order to create a base drawing on each face, and that's working, but in the resulting drawings, each such view is surrounded by the lines of the surrounding visble faces. Can I hide these?

Imagine I'm designing a d10 die, for example, and I want closeups of just each of the 10 faces that I can cut out and glue together on their edges. Can this be done?

Comment: I don't use Fusion 360 but it sounds as though you should have designed the tank with each side an individual part. That way you could create individual part drawings without any references to the others.

Comment: In AutoCAD and other products in there family of software, there is usually something called a clipping pane.  It allows you decide how far away from the section plane you want to include information.  There is usually a fore and aft clipping plane.  May want to look into those terms in Fusion 360 help